# ZF2 dynamic routes

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I need to build dynamic multi level routing in zf2, but not sure what way to approach it. What i need is:

/listing[/:directory1[/:directory2[/dir...]] as unlimited nesting to mimic a directory structure.

Ideally all directories should come either as an array or at least a single variable like "directory1/directory2/directory3...".

i can not find anywhere ho to properly set up these parameters or even if zf2 supports that kind of routing. My current route config looks like this:

```
...
        'gallery' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/Gallery',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Gallery',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'listing' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/listing[/:directory1[/:directory2]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'directory1' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'directory2' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Listing',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

1. Use a [regex route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-regex) and pick the URL apart in your controller.
2. Create your own route by implementing [RouteInterface](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Router/RouteInterface.php).

Comment: Hi, thnx, the regex route worked. it will require some additional security mesures, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using regex route:

```
...
                    'listing' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/listing',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'user' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Listing',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'directory' => array(
                            'type' =>'regex',
                            'options' => array(
                                'regex' => '/(?<dirPath>.*)',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                                    'controller' => 'Listing',
                                    'action' => 'index',
                                ),
                                'spec' => '/%dirPath%',
                            ),


                        ),
...
```

inside controller $directory = $this->params()->fromRoute('dirPath'); returns a url string that can be parsed.